# Looking for help overriding my theme's font color

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some basic knowledge of html and css and use wordpress. I have been able to change the font for the text on my homepage slider by changing the css in my child theme where the #slideshow p, h1, ect are defined and I was able to change it to #fff. I recently updated my theme and now there is this code that takes precedent:

```
#slideshow .bwg_slideshow_description_text * {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

I have tried unsuccessfully to over ride it using:

```
#slideshow .bwg_slideshow_description_text[style] {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

When I look at where this #000 code is coming from, it says it is in a file called index and the doc type is html. I'm not sure if this is something that is auto populated but I cannot find it using filezilla. When I use firebug to inspect the site and search for bwg_slideshow_description_text, the #000 code is showing up under adventurahoy.com #6 and I cannot find it in any of the style sheets.

Can anyone help me with this? The issue is with the text on the slider on the homepage of adventureahoy.com. I would like it to be white and it is showing up as black.

Thank you!

Comment: if you see the color on the page then you should be able to inspect it , you use firebug ( i like chrome) I just right -click on chrome and then inspect element and it will show the styles that have gone into that element and once you find the style then in the style.css of the child just put it at the end

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that by trying to style it to while and putting that code at the end of my style.css but the browser still uses the #000 !important code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this quick fix

```
#slideshow .bwg_slideshow_description_text * {
    color: #fff !important;
}

span.business_elite.btn_trans {
    border-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Usually WP Plugins include filters for a situation like this, where you could override it via a callable php function/closure. However, this should do the trick. Note that if this doesn't work for you, then the plugin is using javascript to override the stylesheet rules. That'll require a follow-up answer.

Comment: I tried this and the php code you suggested. Neither worked unfortunately. Thank you for your help though!  It does seem like this styling is in the javascript since I searched every css stylesheet on my website and couldn't find this code on any of them: 

    #slideshow .bwg_slideshow_description_text * {
        color: #000 !important;
    }

Comment: actually, I posted this css into the area for custom code in my theme's customizer rather than my stylesheet and that worked! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!! I spent many hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Gotcha! I forgot most themes have a custom.css file or something similar. This is included after the primary theme css (usually style.css), and therefore its selectors' styles take precedence. I tend to build my own themes, have a pretty custom setup on one project so it's been awhile working with the normal setup. Using the customizer / custom.css will ensure that your custom styles aren't wiped on theme updates and enqueued at the correct time -- which is really the important thing here.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe targeting wrong elements by using:

```
#slideshow .bwg_slideshow_description_text[style]
```

Reason is that it will target all childrend of `#slideshow` with class `bwg_slideshow_description_text` with a `style` attribute i.e. elements with inline style. But this rule:

```
#slideshow .bwg_slideshow_description_text *
```

targets child elements of `bwg_slideshow_description_text`.

So, the correct selector will be a **more specific selector**. Try this

```
#slideshow div.bwg_slideshow_description_text * {
    color: #FFF!important;
}
```

If you want to target only the `h1`, then you can use:

```
#slideshow div.bwg_slideshow_description_text h1 {
    color: #FFF!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is actually printing the css into the document, most likely using the wp_head hook and probably after any other css that you'll be implementing -- meaning it gets priority. So you'll need to overwrite IT then... You'll need a php solution:

Add the following to your functions.php

```
add_action("wp_head", function(){
    $css  = "<style>";
    $css .= "#slideshow .bwg_slideshow_description_text * {color: #fff !important;}"
    $css .= "span.business_elite.btn_trans {border-color: #fff !important;}";
    $css .= "</style>";
}, 50);
```

If you get a fatal error, you must be using PHP5.2 -- upgrade or change code to:

```
function custom_white_slider_text(){
    $css  = "<style>";
    $css .= "#slideshow .bwg_slideshow_description_text * {color: #fff !important;}"
    $css .= "span.business_elite.btn_trans {border-color: #fff !important;}";
    $css .= "</style>";
});
add_action("wp_head", "custom_white_slider_text", 50);
```

And if that still doesn't do it, then try changing "wp_head" to "wp_footer", or decrease the priority level aka increase the third parameter so it executes later. It defaults to 10, so that's probably when the plugin hooks into the  tag. I've listed 50 above, so that should give you some space between.